# How to install only one of the suggested/recommended packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

For example, Package `master` depends on `dep1` and suggests `sugg1`, `sugg2`. when I install master, `dep1` gets installed automatically but `sugg1`, `sugg2` is not.

I want to install `sugg1` but not `sugg2`. Also I want `sugg1` to be treated as dependency. i.e. 1. If master is uninstalled, `sugg1` should also be removed. 2. If a newer version of master no longer suggests `sugg1`, it should be removed automatically.

What is the correct way to install such non-default dependencies? (not all of them by default. But as and when I choose to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot tell apt to modify its logic to treat some 'suggests' as something else.

But you can tell apt to install the `sugg1` package (it's already a dependency). Then tell apt to treat the package as automatically-installed, so it's eligible for autoremoval.

Looks something like this:

```
# Install master, dependencies, and sugg1
sudo apt install master sugg1
sudo apt-mark auto sugg1

# Uninstall master, dependencies, and sugg1
sudo apt remove master
```

Comment: Thanks! `apt-mark` is what I need exactly.